# How to stick a div to right in Bootstrap properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a layout for showing shopping products of an online store using Bootstrap 3 and it looks like this:

[image: capture]

As you can see there is a gap between **Films** container and the separator line and I need to remove this gap. So the **Films** container would stick to the right side.

And here is the code for that:

```
<section>
    <div class="flex-kit-game-shop-main">
        <!--Books -->
        <div id="training-kit"  style="background-color: #339966 !important;" class="">
            <div class="card bg-transparent border-0 m-r-card">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="title-tab-shop">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            ...
                        </ul>

                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane container active" id="latest-products">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="most-bied">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="popular-products">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!--Films -->
        <div id="training-kit"  style="background-color: #0066ff !important;" class="" >
            <div class="card bg-transparent border-0 m-r-card" >
                <div class="">
                    <div class="title-tab-shop">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            ...
                        </ul>
                        
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane container active" id="latest-products">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="best-selling-products">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="popular-products">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I can stick the **Films** container elements to the right by saying `margin-right:-10px;` but will affect the added products and make them bigger than their normal size.

So how can I properly make this **Films** container stick to the right in Bootstrap?

**CSS File:**

```
.flex-kit-game-shop-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .flex-kit-game-shop-main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the your css file. Find ".flex-kit-game-shop-main" selector. Probably, display value of your top parent div element is "flex"(display:flex;). If it is, I would recommend that you research about conseption of "flexbox" in css. And then, you will be aware of what you should do.

Comment: Yes it is set to `display:flex;`

Answer (score 0):

A better option over here is to use the `float` property in CSS

select the box  you wanna align to a side and then add `float: left;` also remember to clear the float if later you don't wanna use it further, for that add `clear: both;`